# ReplaceRepeated with special characters: Alternatives

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

Following the advice [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210009/replacerepeated-multi-part-pattern), I tried to replace part of an expression guided by the `FullForm` details:

```
-B + b - ((-A + 
      a) \[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE]][(-A + a) (-B + 
         b) | \[ScriptCapitalF]])/\[DoubleStruckCapitalE][(-A + 
       a)^2 | \[ScriptCapitalF]] & // FullForm
```

> Function[Plus[Times[-1, B], b, 
>     Times[-1, 
>      Times[Plus[Times[-1, A], a], [DoubleStruckCapitalE][
>        Alternatives[
>         Times[Plus[Times[-1, A], a], 
>          Plus[Times[-1, B], b]], [ScriptCapitalF]]], 
>       Power[ [DoubleStruckCapitalE][
>         Alternatives[
>          Power[Plus[Times[-1, A], a], 2], [ScriptCapitalF]]], -1]]]]]

However, the replacement rule still does not take effect

```
{-B + b - ((-A + 
       a) \[DoubleStruckCapitalE][(-A + a) (-B + 
          b) | \[ScriptCapitalF]])/\[DoubleStruckCapitalE][(-A + 
        a)^2 | \[ScriptCapitalF]] &} //. {\[DoubleStruckCapitalE][
    Alternatives[
     Power[Plus[Times[-1, a_], b_], 2], \[ScriptCapitalF]]] -> 
   Power[Plus[Times[-1, a], b], 2]}
```

I'm obviously struggling how to do things in MMA.
Appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing that you meant to use [`Conditioned`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conditioned.html) instead of `Alternatives`:

```
expr = -B + b - ((-A + a) ℰ[(-A + a) (-B + b) | ℱ])/ℰ[(-A + a)^2 | ℱ] &
```

[image]

```
InputForm @ %
```

> -B + b - ((-A + a)*ℰ[(-A + a)*(-B + b) | ℱ])/ℰ[(-A + a)^2 | ℱ] &

```
expr2 = expr /. Alternatives -> Conditioned
```

[image]

```
InputForm @ %
```

> -B + b - ((-A + a)*ℰ[Conditioned[(-A + a)*(-B + b), ℱ]])/ℰ[Conditioned[(-A + a)^2, ℱ]] &

```
expr2 /. ℰ[Conditioned[Power[Plus[Times[-1, a_], b_], 2], ℱ]] :> 
  Power[Plus[Times[-1, a], b], 2]
```

[image]

```
InputForm @ %
```

> -B + b - ((-A + a)*ℰ[Conditioned[(-A + a)*(-B + b), ℱ]])/(-A + a)^2 &

**Note:** I replaced `\[DoubleStruckCapitalE]` with `ℰ`.

Comment: Hmm, does this work using  the `\[Conditioned]` symbol? Checking... yes it does.  Thanks!  Can update your answer to reflect the original question notation, then I'll be able to accept.